# Can't access localhost via internet/ip using MAMP PRO

Tags: localhost, mamp-pro

I have my local web server running fine with MAMP PRO but when I try to access it from another network it doesn't work. I have the Apache port set to 8888 in MAMP and I have opened port 8888 (both UDP and TCP) and directed them to my local ip address in my router config but when I type "http://myexternalip:8888" it just says that it couldn't connect to the server.

I have no firewall and I have tried different port numbers without success. I have also tried the regular MAMP.

What should i do?